# Error message after 'make' when trying to install Cresko Stacks

Tags: software-installation, compiling, make

New to Linux and trying to install the CRESKO STACKS programme - when I try and make stacks, I get the error message at the bottom of the text below.

Can anyone explain in layman's terms what this is and how I get around it?

```
make  all-am
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/jamie/Desktop/stacks-1.22'
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.    -fopenmp  -g -O2 -std=gnu++0x -MT src/ustacks-ustacks.o -MD -MP -MF src/.deps/ustacks-ustacks.Tpo -c -o src/ustacks-ustacks.o `test -f 'src/ustacks.cc' || echo './'`src/ustacks.cc
mv -f src/.deps/ustacks-ustacks.Tpo src/.deps/ustacks-ustacks.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.    -fopenmp  -g -O2 -std=gnu++0x -MT src/ustacks-stacks.o -MD -MP -MF src/.deps/ustacks-stacks.Tpo -c -o src/ustacks-stacks.o `test -f 'src/stacks.cc' || echo './'`src/stacks.cc
mv -f src/.deps/ustacks-stacks.Tpo src/.deps/ustacks-stacks.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.    -fopenmp  -g -O2 -std=gnu++0x -MT src/ustacks-mstack.o -MD -MP -MF src/.deps/ustacks-mstack.Tpo -c -o src/ustacks-mstack.o `test -f 'src/mstack.cc' || echo './'`src/mstack.cc
mv -f src/.deps/ustacks-mstack.Tpo src/.deps/ustacks-mstack.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.    -fopenmp  -g -O2 -std=gnu++0x -MT src/ustacks-mst.o -MD -MP -MF src/.deps/ustacks-mst.Tpo -c -o src/ustacks-mst.o `test -f 'src/mst.cc' || echo './'`src/mst.cc
mv -f src/.deps/ustacks-mst.Tpo src/.deps/ustacks-mst.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.    -fopenmp  -g -O2 -std=gnu++0x -MT src/ustacks-cmb.o -MD -MP -MF src/.deps/ustacks-cmb.Tpo -c -o src/ustacks-cmb.o `test -f 'src/cmb.cc' || echo './'`src/cmb.cc
mv -f src/.deps/ustacks-cmb.Tpo src/.deps/ustacks-cmb.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.    -fopenmp  -g -O2 -std=gnu++0x -MT src/ustacks-DNASeq.o -MD -MP -MF src/.deps/ustacks-DNASeq.Tpo -c -o src/ustacks-DNASeq.o `test -f 'src/DNASeq.cc' || echo './'`src/DNASeq.cc
mv -f src/.deps/ustacks-DNASeq.Tpo src/.deps/ustacks-DNASeq.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.    -fopenmp  -g -O2 -std=gnu++0x -MT src/ustacks-DNANSeq.o -MD -MP -MF src/.deps/ustacks-DNANSeq.Tpo -c -o src/ustacks-DNANSeq.o `test -f 'src/DNANSeq.cc' || echo './'`src/DNANSeq.cc
mv -f src/.deps/ustacks-DNANSeq.Tpo src/.deps/ustacks-DNANSeq.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.    -fopenmp  -g -O2 -std=gnu++0x -MT src/ustacks-models.o -MD -MP -MF src/.deps/ustacks-models.Tpo -c -o src/ustacks-models.o `test -f 'src/models.cc' || echo './'`src/models.cc
mv -f src/.deps/ustacks-models.Tpo src/.deps/ustacks-models.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.    -fopenmp  -g -O2 -std=gnu++0x -MT src/ustacks-utils.o -MD -MP -MF src/.deps/ustacks-utils.Tpo -c -o src/ustacks-utils.o `test -f 'src/utils.cc' || echo './'`src/utils.cc
mv -f src/.deps/ustacks-utils.Tpo src/.deps/ustacks-utils.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.    -fopenmp  -g -O2 -std=gnu++0x -MT src/ustacks-kmers.o -MD -MP -MF src/.deps/ustacks-kmers.Tpo -c -o src/ustacks-kmers.o `test -f 'src/kmers.cc' || echo './'`src/kmers.cc
mv -f src/.deps/ustacks-kmers.Tpo src/.deps/ustacks-kmers.Po
g++ -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I.    -fopenmp  -g -O2 -std=gnu++0x -MT src/ustacks-input.o -MD -MP -MF src/.deps/ustacks-input.Tpo -c -o src/ustacks-input.o `test -f 'src/input.cc' || echo './'`src/input.cc
mv -f src/.deps/ustacks-input.Tpo src/.deps/ustacks-input.Po
g++ -fopenmp  -g -O2 -std=gnu++0x -fopenmp  -o ustacks src/ustacks-ustacks.o src/ustacks-stacks.o src/ustacks-mstack.o src/ustacks-mst.o src/ustacks-cmb.o src/ustacks-DNASeq.o src/ustacks-DNANSeq.o src/ustacks-models.o src/ustacks-utils.o src/ustacks-kmers.o src/ustacks-input.o  -lz -lgomp 
src/ustacks-ustacks.o: In function `GzFasta':
/home/jamie/Desktop/stacks-1.22/src/gzFasta.h:42: undefined reference to `gzbuffer'
src/ustacks-ustacks.o: In function `GzFastq':
/home/jamie/Desktop/stacks-1.22/src/gzFastq.h:51: undefined reference to `gzbuffer'
src/ustacks-ustacks.o: In function `write_results(std::map<int, MergedStack*, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, MergedStack*> > >&, std::map<int, Stack*, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, Stack*> > >&, std::map<int, Rem*, std::less<int>, std::allocator<std::pair<int const, Rem*> > >&)':
/home/jamie/Desktop/stacks-1.22/src/ustacks.cc:1433: undefined reference to `gzbuffer'
/home/jamie/Desktop/stacks-1.22/src/ustacks.cc:1441: undefined reference to `gzbuffer'
/home/jamie/Desktop/stacks-1.22/src/ustacks.cc:1449: undefined reference to `gzbuffer'
src/ustacks-ustacks.o:/home/jamie/Desktop/stacks-1.22/src/ustacks.cc:1667: more undefined references to `gzbuffer' follow
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make[1]: *** [ustacks] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/jamie/Desktop/stacks-1.22'
make: *** [all] Error 2
jamie@jamie-HP-255-G1-Notebook-PC:~/Desktop/stacks-1.22$
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you try stacks-1.23. http://creskolab.uoregon.edu/stacks/ It compiles for me successfully with:

```
sudo apt-get install zlib1g-dev 
cd ~/path/to/stacks-1.23
./configure
make
```

I chose not to actually install it on my own system, but the next step is:

```
sudo make install
```